# select rows where same column values start with string, 2 questions

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, substring, case

I'm trying to get multiple sums of rows, each sum has a matching column string value, and all the values have a matching 4 character prefix, but it's not working and I could use some help. Also, would CASE be a more or less costly query on the db?
Started with this:

```
$sql = 
"SELECT col1
FROM table
WHERE substr(col1,1,5)='$string'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$results = $row['col1'];
$sum1 = count(array_keys($results,'string1'));
$sum2 = count(array_keys($results,'string2'));
```

Does it work to get the results from the same column that's in the WHERE clause?

In practice, col1 has row values like aaaa_string1, aaaa_string1, aaaa_string2, aaaa_string2, bbbb_string8...  so I'm looking to get all col1 results that have the aaaa in an array, then subsequently filter how many exist of each string1 and string2.

Comment: could you explain me what you want extract form the table and the column string  .. show  proper data sample and the expected result .. (i think this could be done directly in sql)

Comment: `$results` is a string, not an array, what are you expecting `array_keys($results, 'string1')` to return?

Comment: The best way to match the beginning of a column is with `WHERE col1 LIKE '$string%'`

Comment: I've editted the question for a more concise picture of what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: @scaisEdge see edit

Comment: @stkmedia  . i have posted  . and answer  jope is useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUBSTR(col1, LENGTH('$string')+1)` to get the part of the column after the prefix, and group by this.

Use `LIKE 'prefix%'` to match a column beginning with a prefix.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col1, LENGTH('$string')+1) AS suffix, COUNT(*) as count
FROM table
WHERE col1 LIKE '$string%'
GROUP BY suffix
```

Then you can use a loop to create an associative array with all the counts:

```
$counts = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) {
    $counts[$row['suffix']] = $row['count'];
}
var_dump($counts);
```

Comment: I think you both gave good answers, I'll be back in a while to test and check answered

Comment: I've added to the answer showing how to get all the results.

Comment: Thank you very much Barmar, showing a good understanding in mysql, I should really find time to study more

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you code seems that you are trying to get the cout for substring 'string1' or 'string2' in col1

```
 "select col1,  count(*) as  col_count
 from table
 WHERE substr(col1,1,5)= '$string' 
 and col1 in ('string1','string2')
 group by  col1"
```

You should retrive the result in col_string and col_count

for suffix (assuming  char 6  to end)

```
 "select bstr(col1, 6, 100),  count(*) as  col_count
 from table
 WHERE substr(col1,1,5)= '$string' 
 and substr(col1, 6, 100) in ('string1','string2')
 group by  bstr(col1, 6, 100)"
```

Comment: I'm looking to get the count of the rows that have string1 and also count of rows with string2 suffix, but only from rows that have the aaaa prefix

Comment: `string1` and `string2` are the suffix, not the prefix.

Comment: i have update the answer   you are looking for col1 and not substr  then  if $tring = 'aaaaa'  (1,5)   the query should return two row one for string1  one for string2  i

Comment: I think you both gave good answers, I'll be back in a while to test and check answered