# PHP mysqli group by column_1 and ends with column_2

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to group data from my `mysql` database which has column_1 as the first value and column_2 as a sub that makes it as a pair, so my idea is to group them using two columns.

```
"SELECT * FROM products GROUP BY column_1,column_2"
```

Now my problem is that the column_2 value varies because of abbreviations
example `Apple` sometimes is `Apl` so not every data is group as i planned but there's a suffix that is common with the data example `AppleCS` and `AplCS` so the idea is to capture the last two characters of column_2 with ends with `CS` or `SS`

Now back to grouping on mysql that i cannot figure out how to execute, so logic statement is below.

```
"SELECT * FROM products GROUP BY column_1 and column_2 that ends with `CS` OR `SS`
```

And the last part is to capture duplicate entries so i need to count each data that returns as true,  which adding on the query string.

```
"SELECT *,COUNT(*) AS total FROM products GROUP BY column_1 and column_2 that ends with `CS` OR `SS`
```

My target

[image]

Any suggestion would be great, thanks in advance!

### Edit

As for reference below solved my problem, but i am still looking at other methods if still not the best way of doing it.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as total, RIGHT(column_2,  2) as sub FROM products GROUP BY column_1,sub ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Hope, this answer will help you to fix your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40493472/select-rows-where-same-column-values-start-with-string-2-questions

Comment: I attempted an answer, but it's a speculation.  You should update your question with actual data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i updated my question to add the data that i am dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT
    RIGHT(column_1, 2),
    RIGHT(column_2, 2),
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM products
WHERE
    RIGHT(column_1, 2) IN ('CS', 'SS') AND
    RIGHT(column_2, 2) IN ('CS', 'SS')
GROUP BY
    RIGHT(column_1, 2),
    RIGHT(column_2, 2)
```

Comment: I got it sorted out using the `RIGHT()` method, your answer gave me the clue thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To capture the last two characters of column_2 that end with with 'CS' OR 'SS', you will write:
 `column_2 LIKE '%CSS' OR column_2 LIKE '%SS'`. I wonder that answers your question.